# Combining match filter in the aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If I'm having an object `Post` with two properties

- `Title` of type string
- `IsHomePage` of type boolean
- `IsTagged` of type boolean

**Scenario**: total number of documents is 100. Those with `IsHomePage` set to `true` is `20 in total`, the rest (`80 in total` documents) are documents with property `IsTagged` set to `true`.

how can I construct a query to select all 20 with IsHomePage and the random docs where IsTagged set to true with limit 50?

Comment: Seems like a trivial [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) will suffice. Is there any special logic that is required? you may want to elaborate more by providing sample data end expected output.

Comment: @ray, yes I just update the question

Comment: and the reason why I'm asking for aggregation example is that I want to use power of sample operator in order to select random docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$unionWith` to combine your 2 logic.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      IsHomePage: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            IsHomePage: {
              $ne: true
            },
            IsTagged: true
          }
        },
        {
          "$sample": {
            "size": 50
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P89p55Ay-1x) for your reference.